# Emulador de Android Studio mata el proceso

Tags: android

Cuando intento abrir el emulador de Android Studio con el hola mundo! (recien lo instale), obtengo este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le doy click en No mata el proceso, pero si le doy si obtengo:

**02/13 13:31:46: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 27.
Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_27 was killed.**

Tendra algo que ver los requisitos de hardware:

Tengo un i5 4440 de cuarta generacion con 4gb ddr3 1600, se que es poco. tengo un disco de estado solido ademas. Lo que he notado es que a veces se reinicia mi computadora, tengo Windows 10

Que puedo hacer

Comment: Pues ya de por si el mensaje te dice que la cantidad de memoria ram que tienes libre es bajo, seria recomendable que ampliaras la memoria ram de tu equipo al menos a 8Gb, y si te es posible aumentarla a 16GB mejor, mi equipo es de 2da generacion y con 16GB y el SSD el android studio y AVD corren como si nada pasara.

Answer (score 1):

El error que describes pueden ser varias cosas:

> Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD
>   Pixel_2_API_27 was killed.

Una puede ser la carencia de memoria para poder iniciar correctamente el emulador, me parece que 4GB podría ser suficiente pero probablemente tienes procesos que están consumiendo la mayoría de la memoria.

---

Si usas Windows, primeramente ve a "SDK Tools" y revisa que tengas instalado el "Emulator Accelerator":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Ahora, si usas Windows 10 probablemente tienes problema con los graficos, te sugiero ir a el AVD, editalo y cambiar "Emulated Performance"-> "Graphics" a "Software"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, los dos paths de la imagen no eran coincidentes (en las imágenes sí, luego de cambiarlo).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]